# Move constructors and rvalue references

Tags: c++, constructor, move-semantics

```
class Foo {
    int m_num;
public:
    Foo() {}

    Foo(int& n) {m_num = n;}

    Foo(int&& n) {m_num = n;}

    Foo(const Foo& src) {m_num = src.m_num;}

    Foo(Foo&& src) {m_num = src.m_num;}

    Foo& operator =(const Foo& src) {
        m_num = src.m_num;
        return *this;
    }

    Foo& operator =(Foo&& src) {// move
        m_num = src.m_num;
        return *this;
    }

    int& operator =(const int& src) {return m_num = src;}

    int& operator =(int&& src) {return m_num = src;}
};
```

Why is it that when I call `Foo f4(Foo(2));` it calls the `Foo(int&& n)` constructor instead of `Foo(Foo&& src)` constructor?
Also why doesn't passing num which is an rvalue reference call move constructors?
For example, `Foo f = num` does not call the move constructor.

```
int main() {
    int&& num = 5;
    /*int num{ 5 };*/ // initializer-list
    Foo f = num; // custom constructor
    f = num; // assignment operator
    Foo f2 = 6; // custom move constructor
    f2 = 10; // custom move assignment
    f2 = f; // assignment operator
    Foo f3(f); // custom constructor
    // f3(f2); // ERROR
    f3 = (f2); // assignment operator

    Foo f4(Foo(2));
```

Answer (score 3):

In  `Foo(2)`, the integer is an rvalue and an rvalue reference constructor from `int&&` is needed.

In case of

```
 Foo f = num; // custom constructor
```

The rvalue constructor is not called, because named values are never treated as rvalue. You must call `std::move(num)` to make it work.

The standard defines it this way to avoid confusing cases when named values are moved unexpectedly, and later used. You must be explicit about the move, even if the variable is an rvalue reference.

## edit

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) a c++17 compiler must elide the copy/move constructor of (i.e. it must not call or require the existence of a copy/move constructor in this case, and that's why you see only the constructor from `int&&`):

```
Foo f4(Foo(2));
```

Here is a quote from cppreference (which is not as good as the standard, but close enough):

> the language rules ensure that no copy/move operation takes place,
>   even conceptually:
>
> - In the initialization of a variable, when the initializer expression
>     is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the
>     variable type:
>
>   T x = T(T(T())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you explain to me why Foo(2) returns an integer? I understand that it is an anonymous object but in its constructor body there is no return statement.

Comment: @sangminpark Foo(2) does not return anything, only the constructed Foo object. Foo(2) constructs Foo with `int&&`, and the outer copy/move constructor is elided. You can write Foo(Foo(Foo(Foo(2)))) and the only constructor you get is Foo(2). All othet copy/move constructors are getting elided. I'm not a language lawyer, and I'm uncertain whether this is mandated by c++17 for this case, but compilers do it anyway. It's easy to check if compilers think that copy elision is mandated here, by simply deleting the copy and move constructors and watch the error.

Comment: I don't have the standard at hand to check, but I'm pretty sure that even if a copy would be elided, if the copy ctor is declared as deleted, the code would fail to compile with a 'reference to deleted function' diagnostic.

Comment: @divinas as I've suspected, newer clang and gcc guarantee this copy elision in C++17 mode (despite deleted copy ctor), but not in c++14 mode. Not sure what the standard says

Comment: According to cppreference, in C++17 these copy/move constructors are guaranteed to be elided, and should not be required to exist. Adding this to the answer